# Cannot autowire service RefreshedTokenListener: argument "$ttl" of method construct() is type-hinted "int", you should configure its value explicitly

Tags: symfony5

I have a listener with an argument in __construct named `$ttl` and type-hinted as int, so is the value of a ttl in seconds. I take this value from a config YAML file.

I declared the service with an `$ttl` argument, it seems explicitly declared to me. But now symfony fails until I fix it. I can't even clear the cache.

The error I see is:

> Cannot autowire service RefreshedTokenListener: argument "$ttl" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "int", you should configure its value explicitly

and the listener code begins with:

```
class RefreshedTokenListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private int $ttl;

    public function __construct(int $ttl)
    {
        $this->ttl = $ttl;
    }
    ...
```

and the service is declared as:

```yaml
    services:

        _defaults:
            autowire: true 
            autoconfigure: true
        UserBundle\:
            resource: '../../../'
            exclude:
                - '../../../Domain/Entity/'
                - '../../../Infrastructure/Repository/'
                - '../../../Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/'
        ...
        app.listener.refreshedtokenlistener:
            class: UserBundle\Application\Listeners\RefreshedTokenListener
            arguments:
              $ttl: '%gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.ttl%'
```

I tried to force a fix number in `$ttl` argument of `__construct()`

```
arguments:
    $ttl: 8990000
```

But still same error message that I should configure its value explicitly

I can't see what is wrong, but it's not working. I'm using symfony 5.1, php 7.4.8

I just removed completely the `app.listener.refreshedtokenlistener` declaration lines, so the error should disappear. But same error remains, so this service must be auto-declared somewhere, and that's the error I see. How can I find the error? I don't see any information about this on dev.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're declaring your service using an [alias instead of its full classname](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring). Currently, your service is never autowired.

You must do something like this:

```yaml
services:
    # ...

    app.listener.refreshedtokenlistener:
        class: UserBundle\Application\Listeners\RefreshedTokenListener
        arguments:
            $ttl: '%gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.ttl%'

    UserBundle\Application\Listeners\RefreshedTokenListener: '@app.listener.refreshedtokenlistener'
```